# Why there is a need of two queues in the multiqueue block layer in Linux

Tags: io, linux-kernel

- I am trying to understand the details of Linux multi-queue block layer.
- It is mentioned in the paper title "Linux Block IO: Introducing Multi-queue SSD Access on
  Multi-core System" that there are two queues (Software staging queues and Hardware dispatch queues
  ) in the block layer.
- I am not able to understand why two queues are required i.e. why do we need 'Hardware dispatch queues' (represented by struct blk_mq_hw_ctx) in the block layer?
- Why alone 'Software staging queues' (represented by blk_mq_ctx) are not sufficient?

I have read the Linux kernel documentation regarding multi-queue block layer (https://docs.kernel.org/block/blk-mq.html) and read the paper (https://kernel.dk/systor13-final18.pdf).